# Cloudwatch data logs to create a custom dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch

So I am working on creating my own dashboard for AWS instances, I am trying to determine is there any way to get AWS cloud watch metrics log so that I can get the data and plot it in a graph.
I have been working with AWS CLI but wasn't able to get a perfect way to resolve my query. 
I just need the metrics like

CPU utilization vs time

Disk Utilization vs time

Network Out/In vs time

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS CloudWatch API can do this for you, the two actions you may need:

**GetMetricStatistics**: get time-series data for one or more statistics of a given MetricName.

- CLI reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/cli/cli-mon-get-stats.html
- API docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html

**ListMetrics**: lists the names, namespaces, and dimensions of the metrics associated with your AWS account. You can filter metrics by using any combination of metric name, namespace, or dimensions.

- CLI reference:
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/cli/cli-mon-list-metrics.html
- API docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_ListMetrics.html

Apart from the CLI there are also a bunch of SDKs for different languages (Java, .NET, Ruby, JavaScript etc.) that you can use to call AWS APIs. You can find these in the official AWS github repo: https://github.com/aws